# Does this design for Factory of Domain objects make sense?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, factory, factory-pattern

I am making a factory for my domain objects. Domain objects are prototype objects so they get instantiated quite frequently when the business logic runs. Following is the design:

**1) Some domain interfaces and classes:**

```
public interface FirstDomainInterface {}

public class FirstDomainClass implements FirstDomainInterface {

    private String firstName;

    private int phoneNumber;

    public FirstDomainClass(String firstName, int phoneNumber) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

public interface SecondInterface {}

public class SecondDomainClass implements SecondInterface {

    private long accountNumber;

    private BigDecimal balance;

    public SecondDomainClass(long accountNumber, BigDecimal balance) {
        super();
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.balance = balance;
}
```

**2) Interface declaring method which returns constructor for type of object required from the factory**

```
public interface ObjectConfig {
    public Constructor<?> getConstructor() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException;
}
```

**3) Implementations of Interface declared in second point**

```
public enum FirstModuleConfig implements ObjectConfig {

    FirstTypeObject {

        @Override
        public Constructor<?> getConstructor() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
            Constructor<FirstDomainClass> constructor = FirstDomainClass.class.getConstructor(String.class, int.class);
            return constructor;
        }           
    }
}

public enum SecondModuleConfig implements ObjectConfig {

    SecondTypeObject {

        @Override
        public Constructor<?> getConstructor() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
            Constructor<SecondDomainClass> constructor = SecondDomainClass.class.getConstructor(long.class, BigDecimal.class);
            return constructor;
        }           
    }
}
```

**4) The Factory which instantiates the object**

```
public class Factory {

    public Object createInstance(ObjectConfig config, Object...args) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException  {

        return config.getConstructor().newInstance(args);
    }
}
```

**5) Finally using the factory:**

```
public class FactoryTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {

        Factory factory = new Factory();

        FirstDomainInterface firstTypeObject = (FirstDomainInterface) factory.createInstance(FirstModuleConfig.FirstTypeObject,"myName",12345);

        SecondInterface secondTypeObject = (SecondInterface)factory.createInstance(SecondModuleConfig.SecondTypeObject, 123455232l,BigDecimal.ZERO);

    }

}
```

How does this look?

**Potential advantages which I see:**

1) For each new interface/class I make, I just need to declare it's constructor in one of the Enum implementing ObjectConfig Interface

2) Looks a clean design to me. I won't have to implement a full fledged factory for all my domain objects. Just needed to implement a single method which returns constructor to be used for instantiation.

3) Can inject this single Factory to all services which need to create my domain objects

**Disadvantages I suspect:**

1) Potential runtime exceptions due to class cast, parameters mismatch etc.

2) Slow due to use of reflection?

**Note that this is meant to be used for instantiating prototype domain/business objects by the service layer.** For singleton service and controller beans, I am using Spring Container which gets those beans ready during startup.

Thanks!

Comment: This question would be better off at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.  The question I'd ask up front is "why are you doing this?"

Comment: What is wrong with a basic factory or, behold, just `new instance()`. Why this contraption...

Comment: @M.Deinum There are too many domain classes. This way the instantiation logic will be at one place. I'll just need to register the constructors whenever I make a new class. If I go with SimpleFactory, then there will be too many simple factories for different type of objects and then injecting those different factories at different places as required will be another task. Using this, I just need to inject this single factory in each service class. Something wrong in this thought process?

Comment: As far as using 'new' is concerned, suppose I make a new class called FirstDomainClassTwo implementing FirstDomainInterface and want all the instances of FirstDomainInterface to be of this FirstDomainClassTwo class. Then I will just need to change the constructor in getConstructor() method of FirstType Enum and it will be reflected throughout the application.

Comment: I'm still struggling to see what the actual /problem/ you're trying to solve is

Comment: @MrWiggles I am just trying to make an object which can return me instances of a particular type of Interface. That object will be a single point of instantiation which will decide which concrete class should be used to instantiate the object.

Comment: And trying to avoid making simple factory or static factory method for each type of domain object.

Comment: I don't see how a normal factory wouldn't help you with this, this is just a contraption that makes your code complex and hard to understand. It adds no benefit and seems like an optimization done to early. Also if it is for prototype beans you can also define them in a Spring context and simply do a lookup. It looks to me as if you have a (to complex) solution looking for a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are several advantages of using static factories. Using factory to create classes seems a good approach.

However I would make the following comments that you could consider in your implementation.

1. Consider restricting public constructors to package private and allow only Factory methods. The factory should be in the same package.  So you could also make an instance controlling factory and that you enforce consistent usage of the factory methods. Otherwise fellow programmers in your team (or you in the future) could end up using both factories and constructors.
2. Using functions such as this:

> public Object createInstance(ObjectConfig config, Object...args)

You save some typing time during programming but you loose a lot of the checks your compiler would make in compile time and maybe you increase the chances for more runtime errors. This practice should be avoided in general.

3. Performance is surely worse, so if you do have to maintain your code, why not adding a dedicated factory method for each class. It would be just a delegation call to the package private constructor. Simple to read, simple to write.

There is a good description about the factory methods in the first section of Effective Java Second Edition of Joshua Bloch. You could check it before you proceed.

These are some generic remarks however the path you take in your design is related to the purpose that your application will serve.

I would propose something like that:

```
public class Factory{
  public InterfaceA createNewInterfaceA(int argumentInt,String argumentString){
    return new ClassImplementingInterfaceA();
  }
  public InterfaceA createNewInterfaceA(int argumentInt,double argumentDouble){
    return new ClassImplementingInterfaceA(argumentInt,argumentDouble);
  }

}

 ...similar for all other interfaces
```

Comment: Yes, using simple factories is definitely an option. I am exploring the possibility for something cleaner and shorter.